# Securing High Score

Tags: security, post, request

I develop a simple game with an online simple high score.

One way to attack it is spoofing.

I wanted to send out a Post Request containing username and points.
Right now we just looking at sending data, receive it and process it. (=> no anticheat within the game or SQL injection etc)

The Question is:
What possibilities do I have to protect this process client side?
How do baddies hijack a post request, so they can spoof it?
What would be a solution to protect the content of the the request?

greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop fake high scores from being submittable.
You can have the end client digitally sign the high score, but the client could be modified, so that achieves nothing. 
The best you can do is have the high score accompanied by a complete play by play of the game. That way the play by play can be audited to look for suspicious/erroneous behaviour.

Comment: what is the best way to sign a score or message?

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee 100% that your communication will be secure but you can make an attacker's job harder.

If you encrypt the score within the game and send the (encrypted) score to the server you defeat most script kiddies who just downloaded Wireshark and learned to change numbers.

However, a determined attacker can always reverse-engineer your game to determine the encryption key, or even attach a debugger to the game and modify their score right before it's sent.

There are ways to make this more difficult as well but at the end it's a balance of how secure you want your game to be and how much time and effort you're willing to put into it.